# Compare two maps and find differences using Groovy or Java

Tags: groovy

I would like to find difference in two maps and create a new csv file with the difference (and put the difference between **) like below:

Map 1

```
  [
    [cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:22",appId:"G12355"],
    [cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"12-02-16 13:00",appId:"G12356"],
    [cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12300"], 
    [cuInfo:"T15",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"]  
]
```

Map 2

```
[
    [name:"Apple", cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-02-16 10:00",appId:"G12351"],
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:00",appId:"G12352"],
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T16",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:00",appId:"G12353"],
    [name:"Google",cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12301"], 
    [name:"Microsoft",cuInfo:"T15",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"],
    [name:"Microsoft",cuInfo:"T18",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"]  
]
```

How can I get the output csv like below

```
Map 1 data | Map 2 data
service 3;name Apple;
cuInfo;startDate;appId | cuInfo;startDate;appId
T12;*14-02-16 10:00*;*G12351* | T12;*14-01-16 13:22*;*G12355*
T13;*14-01-16 13:00*;*G12352* | T13;*12-02-16 13:00*;*G12356*
service 9;name Google;       
T14;*10-01-16 11:20*;*G12301* | T12;*10-01-16 11:20*;*G12300*
```

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? How do you read and write the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I'm assuming that the list of maps is sorted appropriately so that the comparison is fair, and that both lists are of the same length:

First, create an `Iterator` to traverse both lists simultaneously:

```
@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
class DualIterator implements Iterator<List> {
    Iterator iter1
    Iterator iter2

    boolean hasNext() {
        iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()
    }

    List next() {
        [iter1.next(), iter2.next()]
    }

    void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
}
```

Next, process the lists to get rows for the CSV file:

```
def rows = new DualIterator(list1.iterator(), list2.iterator())
    .findAll { it[0] != it[1] } // Grab the non-matching lines.
    .collect { // Mark the non-matching values.
        (m1, m2) = it
        m1.keySet().each { key ->
            if(m1[key] != m2[key]) {
                m1[key] = "*${m1[key]}*"
                m2[key] = "*${m2[key]}*"
            }          
        }

        [m1, m2]
    }.collect { // Merge the map values into a List of String arrays
        [it[0].values(), it[1].values()].flatten() as String[]
    }
```

Finally, write the header and rows out in CSV format. NOTE: I'm using a proper CSV; your example is actually *invalid* because the number of columns are inconsistent:

```
def writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter('blah.csv'))
writer.writeNext(['name1', 'cuInfo1', 'service1', 'startDate1', 'appId1', 'name2', 'cuInfo2', 'service2', 'startDate2', 'appId2'] as String[])
writer.writeAll(rows)
writer.close()
```

The output looks like this:

```
"name1","cuInfo1","service1","startDate1","appId1","name2","cuInfo2","service2","startDate2","appId2"
"Apple","T12","3","*14-02-16 10:00*","*G12351*","Apple","T12","3","*14-01-16 13:22*","*G12355*"
"Apple","T13","3","*14-01-16 13:00*","*G12352*","Apple","T13","3","*12-02-16 13:00*","*G12356*"
"Google","T14","9","10-01-16 11:20","*G12301*","Google","T14","9","10-01-16 11:20","*G12300*"
```

Comment: @Rosa, it works great, Thanks!! i just added  def m1 = [:]
        def m2 = [:] to code above

Comment: @Rosa, Can you help me please, I edited my code above,  The situation is changed, The length of both lists are not the same and the second list has one more element

Comment: Ok so how is that supposed to affect the output?

Comment: the csv is still the same as above

Comment: The simplest thing to do is determine which of the two lists is the shortest, and add enough maps to it to make it equal to the other list. The map keys must be the same but the values could be empty strings. Then you can use the rest of the code as is.

Comment: @Rosa, Can you help me please with that?

Comment: Not until you give it your best shot.

Comment: @Rosa, sure i will try

Comment: @Rosa, Im able to add extra maps to the shortest list, that is ok, but the result of the csv file is wrong.What I see for example, it compares the first row of list one with the first row of list two. Comparison is on rows and not on content. Idea?

Comment: Remember, my example contained two caveats: *I'm assuming that the **list of maps is sorted appropriately** so that the comparison is fair, and that **both lists are of the same length***. Since both of these no longer apply, my answer is moot. If you can sort the lists so they can be compared by row, then you're good to go. If not, you'll need a completely different strategy.

Comment: @Rosa, Sorry I was not clear with my question, Im really need to compare the content especially cusInfo, startDate, appId, Can you please help me. now I heard I need completely different stategy. I dont have any idea how to start