# Combine two Groovy maps and get differences

Tags: grails, groovy

I have two maps and I would like to combine this maps into new map with the differences. I mean with differences is if **startDate** or **appId** are different for that **cuInfo** and **service**.

Notice: The attributes **cuInfo** and **service** are unique in both maps.

Map 1:

```
[
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-02-16 10:00",appId:"G12351"],
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:00",appId:"G12352"],
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T16",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:00",appId:"G12353"],
    [name:"Google",cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12301"], 
    [name:"Microsoft",cuInfo:"T15",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"]  
]
```

Map 2:

```
[
    [cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:22",appId:"G12355"],
    [cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"12-02-16 13:00",appId:"G12356"],
    [cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12300"], 
    [cuInfo:"T15",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"]  
]
```

I would like to get map below as final result:

```
[
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-02-16 10:00",appId:"G12351",startDate2:"14-01-16 13:22",appId2:"G12355"],
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:00",appId:"G12352",startDate2:"12-02-16 13:00",appId2:"G12356"],
    [name:"Google",cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12301",startDate2:"10-01-16 11:20",appId2:"G12300"]
]
```

I tried the code below but it gives not what I want:

```
def total = [list1: list1, list2: list2].collectEntries { label, maps ->
        [(label): maps.countBy { it.iccId} ]
    }.inject([:]) { result, label, counts ->
        counts.entrySet().each { entry ->
            if(!result[entry.key]) result[entry.key] = [:]
            result[entry.key][(label)] = entry.value
        }
    result
    }.collect { iccId , counts -> [iccId: iccId] << counts }
```

The code above give me this, it merge the maps and count the cuInfos but I'm not able to get the differences:

```
[
[cuInfo:T12, list1:1, list2:1], [cuInfo:T13, list1:1, list2:1], [cuInfo:T14, list1:1, list2:1], [cuInfo:T15, list1:1, list2:1],[cuInfo:T16, list1:1]
]
```

Please who can help to get it work please with example. Thanks

Comment: What about `T15`, should it be in the result as well?

Comment: @Opal, for T15 there no differences in both maps, I mean the startDate and appId are not difference

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear. What differences you need to get? Is the *result* the desired result?

Comment: How does this differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851359/compare-two-maps-and-find-differences-using-groovy-or-java

Comment: @tim_yates, The question is the same I know that, But I dont know how te reopen the question on Stackoverflow. the asnwer of Emmanuel works fine but not what i want. that is why I asked again. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for:

```
def col1 = [
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-02-16 10:00",appId:"G12351"],
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:00",appId:"G12352"],
    [name:"Apple",cuInfo:"T16",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:00",appId:"G12353"],
    [name:"Google",cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12301"], 
    [name:"Microsoft",cuInfo:"T15",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"]  
]  

def col2 = [
    [cuInfo:"T12",service:"3",startDate:"14-01-16 13:22",appId:"G12355"],
    [cuInfo:"T13",service:"3",startDate:"12-02-16 13:00",appId:"G12356"],
    [cuInfo:"T14",service:"9",startDate:"10-01-16 11:20",appId:"G12300"], 
    [cuInfo:"T15",service:"10",startDate:"26-02-16 10:20",appId:"G12999"]  
]

col1
.findAll { it.cuInfo in col2.cuInfo && !(it.subMap('cuInfo', 'service', 'startDate', 'appId') in col2) }
.collect {
    def e = col2.find { i2 -> it.cuInfo == i2.cuInfo }
    it << [startDate2: e.startDate, appId2: e.appId]
}
.each {
    println it 
}
```

?

Comment: I will try it and let you know